# How to assign different names for each text box when placed in a loop in php..?

Tags: php

I had generated few textboxes in a loop n named them differntly.. but the retrieving of data from those boxes is not working.. Please help me..

code for creating those textboxes

```
$i=0;  
while($data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql ))
   { 
       echo "<tr><td>".$data['idno']." </td><td>".$data['name'] . " </td><td>
       <input type='text' name='obtmarks".$i."'></td></tr>";  $i++; 
   }
```

I have to retrieve that data n place it another table

code for retrieving the data

```
$i=0;


while($data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql1 )) 
 { 

    $as=mysql_query("INSERT INTO marks values('".$data['idno']."','".$data['name']."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['obtmarks".$i."'])."')");
 $i++;  }
```

Please help me.. thank u in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you print the textboxes in a form, and post the form back to the retrieval code:

You need to get the variable value from the post array:

```
$i=0;

while($data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql1 )) 
{ 
    var value = $_POST['obtmarks'.$i];

    // insert into database

    $i++;  
}
```

*(Be careful to use the exact same label, in your example you use obmarks and obtmarks.)*

**WARNING** Don't store the value in your database without checking it!! Use prepared statements!!

Comment: can u please guide me abt those prepared statements for this code.

Comment: You should read [this guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Variables bound using prepared statements are escaped automatically by the server, preventing SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$as=mysql_query("INSERT INTO marks values('".$data['idno']."','".$data['name']."','".$_POST['obmarks'.$i]."')");
```

this is assuming you are passing your data through a form submit.